# How are the different events classified according to tiers on the Women's Tennis circuit?

Tags: tennis, wta, gender

On the Men's side, it's fairly simple & unambiguous. Men's tennis events for the season are classified into 3 tiers. ATP Masters 1000, ATP 500 & ATP 250 in decreasing order of importance based on points.

However, on the Women's side, there seems to be 3 tiers but the events are classified as WTA Premier & WTA international in decreasing order of importance based on points. But at this point it gets ambiguous. Taking into account the recent tournaments, WTA Tokyo(concluded today) & WTA Wuhan(starting today) are listed as WTA Premier events. But WTA Tokyo awards 470 points while WTA Wuhan awards 900 points.

So how can I unambiguously classify WTA events based on tiers? Also please list all the WTA events in a season which are Tier 1(900 points events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2009 WTA has reformed categories for tournaments ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_WTA_Tour)).

[Since 2009 tournaments are splitted in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Premier_tournaments):

- **4** Premier Mandatory (1000 points each)
- **5** Premier 5 (900 points)
- **12** Premier (470 points)
- **several** international tournaments (280 points)

Obiovously the most important tournaments are:

- **4** Grand Slam (2000 points each)
- WTA finals (1500 points)

Befor 2009 the tournaments could be: [Tier I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tier_I_tournaments), [Tier II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tier_II_tournaments), [Tier III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tier_III_tournaments), [Tier IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tier_IV_tournaments)

Comment: It seems WTA, changes the category of events faster than comprehension. They downgraded Tokyo & brought in Wuhan in 2014. They did it with Qatar in 2015